# trace trap error in Golang when execute command by Cmd.Run

Tags: go

My program use `os/exec.Cmd` to play mp3 sound with libsox (https://github.com/OUCC/prism/blob/d0b96fe82c1aefb183a0435404e92acd083b6247/kiosk/main.go#L100). But after the sound is played (command is executed), I got following error and program exited.

```
trace trap (core dumped)  kiosk
```

Same problem is happen when I replaced the command with "ls". It's not important which command is executed.

I used debugger to know what's wrong and I got this stack trace:

[image]

I tried to make simple program that cause same program but I failed to do this... Please give me some advice.

go1.4 linux/amd64

**update**
minimal example https://gist.github.com/yuntan/df45e29a00158f0076ef

Comment: Looks like a problem with cgo. I don't know if it's OK at all to exec from within a qml context. I would bring this up with go-qml.

Comment: @JimB Umm... I comment out `qml.Run()` and program runs without any error...

Comment: yes. Like I said, it looks like a cgo problem, and it could be a bug. No on will no better than the go-qml developers. Try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).